# Knockout.js: Separating ViewModel logic from the Model

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, viewmodel

In a video tutorial on the [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) homepage, the presenter sets up a simple example in which the ViewModel contains an `observableArray` property containing instances of a custom object (a "friend" object, in this case):

```
function friend(name) {
  return {
    name: ko.observable(name),
    remove: function () {
      viewModel.friends.remove(this);
    }
  };
}

var viewModel = {
  friends: ko.observableArray()
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

This is then rendered using a KO template:

```
<script id="friendsTemplate" type="text/html">
  <li>
    <input data-bind="value: name" />
    <button data-bind="click: remove">Remove</button>
  </li>
</script>
```

It seems odd to me that the logic for removing a `friend` object (the Model?) from the ViewModel's `friends` collection is implemented in the `friend` object itself.  Doesn't this create an undesirable coupling between the `friend` object and the ViewModel instance?  Is there a more consistent design approach that would allow the `removeFriend` functionality to be defined in the ViewModel rather than in the `friend` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more common pattern would be to put a `removeFriend` function one level higher and the bind to it using:

```
<button data-bind="click: $parent.removeFriend">Remove</button>
```

When Knockout calls the handler from the `click` or `event` binding it will pass the current data item as the first argument.  It will also set the context (`this`) equal to the current data as well. Depending on your structure, you may have to `bind` the function to ensure that it is called with the appropriate context or use a strategy like `var self = this;`.

Since, `viewModel` is an object literal, in this case `removeFriend` could look like:

```
friends: ko.observableArray(),
removeFriend: function(friend) {
    viewModel.friends.remove(friend);
}
```

Comment: I like that a lot better.  Thanks for the answer.